# How to send coinpot to coinbase

Tags: bitcoind

Can I send my crytocurrency in coinpot bitcoincore bitcoincash, mooncash, ect to my coinbase wallet?
How is this done?

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of CoinPot However, if you're referring to the cryptocurrency exchange [Coinbase](https://coinbase.com), as of November 2018 it is only possible to store the [following coins](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2630943-supported-digital-currencies):

- Bitcoin
- Bitcoin Cash
- Ethereum
- Ethereum Classic
- Litecoin
- USDC
- Basic Attention Token
- 0x

This may be different depending on your location (country), use the chart provided to confirm.

Coinbase makes it fairly easy to receive coins, simply press "Receive" under the preferred coin and submit that address in CoinPot's withdraw implementation (You may need to obtain documentation or contact them for instructions on how to do this).